# Find unique values across each row

Tags: numpy

I Have a 2 dimensional numpy array say as follows:

```
[["cat","dog","dog","mouse","man"],
["rhino","rhino","bat","rhino","dino","dino"],
["zebra","alien","alien","alien","alien"]]
```

I want to perform numpy.unique along each row in order to count the number of occurrences of each label, unfortunately I don't think this is possible as numpy.unique would return vectors of different lengths:

```
[["cat","dog","mouse","man"]
["rhino","bat","dino"]
["zebra","alien"]]
(similar then for the counts)
```

so this won't work obviously.

Does anybody know of a way I can get around this problem?

Comment: Use array unique function. doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

If this is not what you are looking for please add the expected result in your question. Thanks.

Comment: @NaveedAhmed `numpy` is a *python* library.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([["cat","dog","dog","mouse","man"],
                  ["rhino","rhino","bat","rhino","dino","dino"],
                  ["zebra","alien","alien","alien","alien"]])

a.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique()), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks this does work for obtaining the unique values, but to get the counts too I am finding tricky for the data set I am actually using. If I use the pd.value_counts method similarly to what you have detailed it would return a matrix with a huge amount of columns due to the fact that I have a high number of potential values. Unsure of how to proceed.